# Ubuntu 16 has unexplained 2nd IP

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16 a while ago, and recently I did a network audit. There was one static IP that I could not trace down, but I eventually found it was tied to this Ubuntu 16 server. When I ping the address it stops responding when I unplug the ethernet cable.

This static IP is in addition to the static IP I assigned to the server manually. I assigned the static IP 192.168.1.2 to the server. The unexplained IP is 192.168.1.5. I can ping 192.168.1.5 from other computers, but when I try to ping it from the Ubuntu 16 computer itself it does not respond.

I know it's possible to set up a NIC to have two IPs, but it is set up for only one right now. Currently the server is only installed with a few basic http server stack packages from the official repos.

Why is this server responding to pings on 192.168.1.5? How do I fix this?

Comment: Based on your dell-poweredge tag, I'd say the additional ip address is probably bound to the iDRAC.

Comment: Looks like this is it! If you post this as an answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your dell-poweredge tag, I'd say the additional ip address is probably bound to the iDRAC.